# Replicate a graph on Wikipedia associated to the Gaussian distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, axis-labels

I want to replicate the graph of Normal density functions available on Wikipedia. I am stuck on the following parts :

- how to put the legend at the bottom (I would like to get lines in the graph and don't know if this is even possible with GGplot)
- the title at the bottom (apparently, one needs to use Grid but I am not able to use it)
  -and the different ticks for the axis, on the border (to divide and subdivide the axis and actually in the border)
- the mathematical function on the label axis that don't appear exactly as in the graph

[image]

```
ggplot(dataset) + geom_line(aes(x=dataset$X.values, 
y=dataset$Y.values.mean.0.and.variance.2), 
color='navyblue') + 
geom_line(aes(x=dataset$X.values, 
y=dataset$Y.values.mean.0.and.variance.1), 
color='red3') + geom_line(aes(x=dataset$X.values, 
y=dataset$Y.values.mean.0.and.variance.5), 
color='tan2') + geom_line(aes(x=dataset$X.values, 
y=dataset$Y.values.mean..2.and.variance.0.5), 
color='forestgreen') + ylim(0,1) + xlim(-5,5) + 
theme_light() + ylab(expression(varphi[sigma^2,] 
[mu^2](x))) + xlab(expression(x)) +  theme_bw() +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = 
"black", size=1))
```

Here is my graph

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do all of that.

### Legend Position

you can re position the legend  using + theme(legend.position="") for example

```
+ theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

would give you a legend across the bottom of your graph.

you can also set the position of the legend according to (x,y) coordinates, I'm pretty sure they scale from 0:1 so something like

```
theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.5))
```

will put your legend dead centre.

### Title position

why not just use caption if you want it on the bottom?

```
+labs(caption="My Magnificent Caption")
```

which by default appears bottom right hand corner, however we can move this too by

```
+theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=20))
```

which would place it in the centre.

### Axis font and Size

if your problem with your axis is your text size, you can change this using +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = n)), for example

```
+ theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20))
```

would make your x-axis title much larger.

```
+ theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20))
```

would do the same for y.

as for font, we can first check what fonts are available using

```
windowsFonts()
```

then we can add whatever font you have avaliable to the element_text function to change font. e.g.

```
+  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20,family="mono"))
```

would give you a large x axis title using the TT Courier New font (on my machine which should only have default fonts and should work for you too).

### Conclusivly

you would likely want something like

```
+labs(caption="My Magnificent Caption")+
 theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.8),
       axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20, family="mono"),
       axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20, family="mono"),
       plot.caption = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=20))
```

Comment: no worries, welcome to stack overflow :)

If the answer fully answers your question, then click the tick under up and down vote buttons on the top left hand side of my initial response. This lets others know its answered, which lets people looking to answer know they don't need need to spend time here and lets others looking for answers to questions like yours know there is an answer here.

if its not fully answered feel free to let me know what you're still having issues with!